# Docker: Staging multiple containers for one application

Tags: architecture, docker

I thought of dockerizing our deployment process. Lets say we have an application containing of several layers (e.g. a DB, a business logic layer and a UI layer (lets say a just a JS based UI but we still need a http server for it)) provided by several containers (a DB container, a data container, a container for the business logic and one for the UI).

For my test environment I'd use a Oracle XE in a container while on production I'd use an existing big Oracle cluster. This means that the deployment is different for several stages.

On the other hand I'd like a simple installation e.g. for a manager installing all the containers all at once (and linked together) on his notebook for a presentation.

How can I manage the deployment of several (dependent) containers in several stages as simple as possible while still being flexible enough for different deployment scenarios?

Comment: I would recommend you to read about kubernetes.

Comment: The generic term, if you want to do web searches, is 'orchestration'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to all docker containers on a single instance I would recommend [fig](http://www.fig.sh/). I have found the workflow to be a lot cleaner and consistent with the docker way than other tools such as [kubernetes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes).

kubernetes does have the advantage that you can use the same deployment processes on Google Container Service for distributed deployments when you get to production. If you are going to deploy to Amazon elastic beanstalk or their new Container Service they have a different json based manifest file.